en un script de python no puedo traer una consulta de una Base PostgreSQL
Tengo el siguiente script en python
#obtengo esta info de un response
    transaction_id = response.json()["objeto"]["id"] 
 #armo la query que obtengo de un archivo de queries ( get_trx_collecting = "select * from corb.trx_collecting where transaction_id = %s")
    query = q.get_trx_collecting 
 # armo el parametro que le voy a enviar a la funcion execute
    param = (transaction_id,)
# mando la informacion a la funcion execute
    db_data = RDSUtils.execute_query(query,param)

# Llamo a la funcion execute
    execute_query(query,param):
        conn = DatabaseDriver.getInstance()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query,param)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        DatabaseDriver.closeDriver()
        return result

El problema que estoy teniendo es que cuando armo la query y le paso el transaction_id por parametro, la consulta de la base de datos no me trae informacion. La consulta es correcta porque la pruebo manualmente y funciona). Pero si yo mando la query hardcodeada ( "select * from
corb.trx_collecting where transaction_id = 'YZ6OLMDN3PGG48W2E7RQ5X' ) con el id directamente ahi si me trae la informacion del registro. El problema que veo es cuando le quiero pasar el transaction_id directamente desde la variable, ahi no me lo reconoce, sin embargo no arroja ningun error la consulta.

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Considero importante que des clic en [edit] la pregunta e incluyas el texto exacto que queda en la variable query. Un saludo.

No sé qué módulo de postgresql estás usando. Ninguno tiene la función execute_query y tu código no dice mucho. Por favor, especifica qué conector de base de datos estás usando y corrige el código para que sea entendible. Nos ayudará mucho para poder ayudarte.
